# Add row in a existing Excel document with styles

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm working with C# 2008 (FW 3.5), OpenXML SDK 2.0 and a Excel 2007 document's.

The program take's values from a Database and create a dynamic table, and the values are pasted in a Excel template.

All this work's fine, but i need something else:

I need create a specified number of new row's in the template, but with styles (border, font, backcolor, etc.) and I don't how to make it.

Someone can help me with a example code for make this?

Thanks a lot and excuse my english.

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation and found nothing better, but use a vb macros in excel document which adds new row and invoke it from .net.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.
It's not possible to me use macros, because in the server Office don't be installed. (security issues).

Answer (score 0):

Rastro,

You can use the following method to do that

```
private UInt32Value createBorder(Stylesheet styleSheet,bool buttomBorderDouble)
        {
            Border border;
            //set borders of header
            if (buttomBorderDouble)
            {


  border = new Border
                (
                new BottomBorder { Style = BorderStyleValues.Double },
                new DiagonalBorder());
        }
        else
        {

             border = new Border
                (
                new BottomBorder {Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin},
                new DiagonalBorder());
        }




        styleSheet.Borders.Append(border);
        UInt32Value result = styleSheet.Borders.Count;
        styleSheet.Borders.Count++;
        return result;

    }
    private UInt32Value createFont(Stylesheet styleSheet, string fontName, Nullable<double> fontSize, bool isBold, System.Drawing.Color foreColor, bool isUnderLine)
    {

        Font font = new Font();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fontName))
        {
            FontName name = new FontName()
            {
                Val = fontName
            };
            font.Append(name);
        }

        if (fontSize.HasValue)
        {
            FontSize size = new FontSize()
            {
                Val = fontSize.Value
            };
            font.Append(size);
        }

        if (isBold == true)
        {
            Bold bold = new Bold();
            font.Append(bold);
        }
        if (isUnderLine == true)
        {
            Underline underline = new Underline();
            font.Append(underline);
        }

        if (foreColor != null)
        {
            Color color = new Color()
            {
                Rgb = new HexBinaryValue()
                {
                    Value =
                        System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(
                            System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(
                                foreColor.A,
                                foreColor.R,
                                foreColor.G,
                                foreColor.B)).Replace("#", "")
                }
            };
            font.Append(color);
        }
        styleSheet.Fonts.Append(font);
        UInt32Value result = styleSheet.Fonts.Count;
        styleSheet.Fonts.Count++;
        return result;
    }

private UInt32Value createCellFormat(Stylesheet styleSheet, UInt32Value fontIndex, UInt32Value fillIndex, UInt32Value numberFormatId, UInt32Value borderId)
        {
            CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat();

            if (fontIndex != null)
                cellFormat.FontId = fontIndex;

            if (fillIndex != null)
                cellFormat.FillId = fillIndex;

            if (numberFormatId != null)
            {
                cellFormat.NumberFormatId = numberFormatId;
                cellFormat.ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);
            }
            if (borderId != null)
                cellFormat.BorderId = borderId;

            styleSheet.CellFormats.Append(cellFormat);

            UInt32Value result = styleSheet.CellFormats.Count;
            styleSheet.CellFormats.Count++;
            return result;
        }
```

and its a piece of code that call these methods

Stylesheet styleSheet = workbook.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet;

```
UInt32Value headerFontIndex =
                createFont(
                    styleSheet,
                    "MS Sans Seif",
                    10,
                    true,
                    System.Drawing.Color.Black, false);

 UInt32Value doubleBorderIndex = createBorder(styleSheet, true);

            UInt32Value headerStyleIndexWithDoubleBottomBorder =
               createCellFormat(
                   styleSheet,
                   headerFontIndex,
                   0,
                   null, doubleBorderIndex);
 Cell _Cell = createTextCell(1, 1, "Intercompany Reconciliation Summary", headerStyleIndexWithDoubleButtomBorder, null);
```

the output of that is to write  **Intercompany Reconciliation Summary** with bold and double lines under it

I hope it help you

```
Thanks,
Mohammed Thabet Zaky
Software Developer
Cairo,Egypt
```